# Small iteration in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, iterator

Hey guys I have a slight problem.

Can somebody show me how I would be able to separate this string into a json formatted data?

```
one:apple;two:orange;three:bananna;four:pears
```

To look like this

```
{
  one: apple,
  two: orange,
  three: bananna,
  four: pears
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`Array#forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over [**`String#split`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
var str = "one:apple;two:orange;three:bananna;four:pears";
var obj = {};
str.split(';').forEach(function(el) {
  var x = el.split(':');
  obj[x[0]] = x[1];
});
console.log(obj);
```

**Or using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)**

*The [**`comma operator`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.*

```js
var str = "one:apple;two:orange;three:bananna;four:pears";
var obj = str.split(';').reduce(function(a, b) {
  var x = b.split(':');
  return a[x[0]] = x[1], a;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you ! Been struggling with it for so long =]

Comment: @VietLe — – I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b2ehv7a1/1/)

```
var str = "one:apple;two:orange;three:bananna;four:pears";
var arr = str.split(';'), obj = {}, i = 0;
for(; i < arr.length; i++){
  var x = arr[i].split(':');
  obj[x[0]] = x[1]
};
console.log(obj);
x = null;

// thanks to @Rayon for edit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do this.

```js
var str = "one:apple;two:orange;three:bananna;four:pears"

var obj = '{"'+ str.replace(/;/g, ',').replace(/[:+,]/g, '"$&"') + '"}'
console.log(JSON.parse(obj))
```